# How to compute $\lim_{n \to \infty}P(C_n>C_0)$?

Tags: probability, central-limit-theorem, law-of-large-numbers

> The unit price of a certain commodity evolves randomly
>   from day to day with a general downward drift but with an occasional
>   upward jump when some unforeseen event excites the markets. Long term
>   records suggest that, independently of the past, the daily price increases by
>   a dollar with probability $0.45$, declines by $2$ dollars with probability $0.5$,
>   but jumps up by $10$ dollars with probability $0.05$. Let $C_0$ be the price today
>   and $C_n$ the price $n$ days into the future. How does the probability $P(C_n>C_0)$
>   behave as $n$ goes to infinity?

My work:

Consider $\lim_{n \to \infty} (C_n>C_0)$ where $Cn=\frac{\Sigma_{i = 1}^{n}X_i}{n}$

where $X_i$ are i.i.d. random variables.
Let $\mu$ be the mean of $X_i$ and $\sigma$ be the standard deviation.

$\lim_{n \to \infty} P(C_n>C_0)=1-P(C_n＜C_0)
＜1-P(|C_{n-m}|＜C_0)
＜(1-(1-\frac{sigma^2}{nC_0^2}))=0$

Comment: I am not confident with the last part.

Comment: Also, do I compute E(X) and Var(X)?

Answer (score 1):

Suppose $D_n = C_n - C_0$. Then $P(C_n > C_0) = P(D_n > 0) = P(\frac{D_n}{n} > 0)$, and $D_n = \Sigma_{k = 1}^{n} X_i$, where $X_i$ are i.i.d. random variables, such that $P(X_i = 1) = 0.45$, $P(X_i = -2) = 0.5$ and $P(X_i = 10) = 0.05$. Then by the Law of Large Numbers $\frac{D_n}{n}$ converges in probability to $EX_i = 0.45*1 + 0.5*(-2) + 0.05*10 = -0.05 < 0$. That results in $P(C_n > C_0) = P(\frac{D_n}{n} > 0) = 0$

You can find more about convergence in probability here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convergence_of_random_variables#Convergence_in_probability